# Optimizing network traffic for a chart with thousands of points

Tags: javascript, optimization, charts, mathematical-optimization, c3.js

## Problem

I'm generating a stacked area chart with [c3js](http://c3js.org/). It will probably contain over thousand points.

The chart will be getting real time updates from the server. Due to the nature of the data I can't stream partial information. I will have to send the full set of 1000+ points over the wire.

There are almost no curves on the chart, Most of the data is expected to be linear or piece-wise linear.

## Question

What would be a good way to minimize that data that needs to be sent over the wire ?

## Current Ideas

- Text Compression algorithms on client and server side
- Since its a linear chart just send the start and end points and generate all the points in between in JavaScript
- If the chart is piece wise linear, just send multiple pieces and group them together.
- Compute a function representing the set of points and send that function over (I have no idea where to begin on this one)

## Edits

Here's the graph,

[image: The Graph]

and the corresponding data points, In this graph the array index is the x-axis point and the point on the y-axis is the value on the array.

This just a sample, There are would be 5 or six more graphs like this which would all change when the inputs change so I'll have to re-render the whole chart.

```
{


"GraphA": [41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 41376, 28963.199999999997, 28963.199999999997, 28963.199999999997, 28963.199999999997, 28963.199999999997, 26894.4, 26894.4, 26894.4, 26894.4, 26894.4, 24825.6, 24825.6, 24825.6, 24825.6, 24825.6, 20688.0, 20688.0, 20688.0, 20688.0, 20688.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 

"GraphB": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 510, 1000, 1480, 1960, 2450, 2930, 3420, 3900, 4380, 4870, 5350, 5840, 6320, 6800, 7290, 7770, 8250, 8740, 9220, 9710, 10190, 10670, 11160, 11640, 12130, 12610, 13090, 13580, 14060, 14550, 15030, 15510, 16000, 16480, 16970, 17450, 17930, 18420, 18900, 19380, 19870, 20350, 20840, 21320, 21800, 22290, 22770, 23260, 23740, 24220, 24710, 25190, 25680, 26160, 26640, 27130, 27610, 28100, 28580, 29060, 29550, 30030, 30510, 31000, 31480, 31970, 32450, 32930, 33420, 33900, 34390, 34870, 35350, 35840, 36320, 36810, 37290, 37770, 38260, 38740, 39230, 39710, 40190, 40680, 41160, 41640, 42130, 42610, 43100, 43580, 44060, 44550, 45030, 45520, 46000, 46480, 46970, 47450, 47940, 48420, 48900, 49390, 49870, 50350, 50840, 51320, 51810, 52290, 52770, 53260, 53740, 54230, 54710, 55190, 55680, 56160, 56650, 57130, 57610, 58100, 58580, 59070, 59550, 60030, 60520, 61000, 61480, 61970, 62450, 62940, 63420, 63900, 64390, 64870, 65360, 65840, 66320, 66810, 67290, 67780, 68260, 68740, 69230, 69710, 70200, 70680, 71160, 71650, 72130, 72610, 73100, 73580, 74070, 74550, 75030, 75520, 76000, 76490, 76970, 77450, 77940, 78420, 78910, 79390, 79870, 80360, 80840, 81330, 81810, 82290, 82780], 

"GraphC": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 73, 143, 212, 281, 350, 419, 488, 557, 626, 696, 765, 834, 903, 972, 1041, 1110, 1179, 1249, 1318, 1387, 1456, 1525, 1594, 1663, 1733, 1802, 1871, 1940, 2009, 2078, 2147, 2216, 2286, 2355, 2424, 2493, 2562, 2631, 2700, 2769, 2839, 2908, 2977, 3046, 3115, 3184, 3253, 3323, 3392, 3461, 3530, 3599, 3668, 3737, 3806, 3876, 3945, 4014, 4083, 4152, 4221, 4290, 4359, 4429, 4498, 4567, 4636, 4705, 4774, 4843, 4913, 4982, 5051, 5120, 5189, 5258, 5327, 5396, 5466, 5535, 5604, 5673, 5742, 5811, 5880, 5949, 6019, 6088, 6157, 6226, 6295, 6364, 6433, 6502, 6572, 6641, 6710, 6779, 6848, 6917, 6986, 7056, 7125, 7194, 7263, 7332, 7401, 7470, 7539, 7609, 7678, 7747, 7816, 7885, 7954, 8023, 8092, 8162, 8231, 8300, 8369, 8438, 8507, 8576, 8646, 8715, 8784, 8853, 8922, 8991, 9060, 9129, 9199, 9268, 9337, 9406, 9475, 9544, 9613, 9682, 9752, 9821, 9890, 9959, 10028, 10097, 10166, 10236, 10305, 10374, 10443, 10512, 10581, 10650, 10719, 10789, 10858, 10927, 10996, 11065, 11134, 11203, 11272, 11342, 11411, 11480, 11549, 11618, 11687, 11756, 11826]

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92974/discussion-on-question-by-gautam-optimizing-network-traffic-for-a-chart-with-tho).

Answer (score 1):

Where `data` is the original dataset:

```
var delta = {
    "GraphA": "41375,,,,,,,,,,,,,49375,41476,41372,41378,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,41399,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,26894.4,26894.4,,,,",
    "GraphB": "41375,,,,,,,,,,,,,49375,41476,41372,41378,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,41399,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,26894.4,26894.4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,",
    "GraphC": "41375,,,,,,,,,,,,,49375,41476,41372,41378,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,41399,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,26894.4,26894.4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,",
}

for(var i in delta){
    delta[i] = delta[i].split(",");
    for(var j in delta[i]){
        if(delta[i][j] == "")
            delta[i][j] = data[i][j] || 0; // fill empty values with data or zero
    }
}

// use delta
```

Comment: I'm doing an improved version of this.

`"GraphA": "0*5", 10, 12,14,16,.... "65*3", "75*3"`

Comment: @Gautam gzip encoding works in a similar manner but it compresses tuples into pointers. You might get better results with just gzip because it finds repeating instances (of commas or `375,` perhaps) and replaces them with pointers. If there will be very little variance gzip alone makes sense. It's possible that processing the data to strip the unchanged values makes less sense than just sending them gzipped, since the algorithm is fast. Another option is adding a binary format like AMF3 at both ends (since its all integer based numbers). http://goo.gl/ZwhG

Comment: Here is a neat visualization on how gzip compression actually works http://jvns.ca/blog/2013/10/24/day-16-gzip-plus-poetry-equals-awesome/

Comment: Yea I am getting almost 50% compression on my GZip tests. 
So I'll be using that. 

I'm also planning to downsample the graph to reduce the number of points that I need to send, Or just send across the line equations for simple linear graphs.